# React rendering output from 'Marked' as text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the [Marked](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/marked) library with React. The problem I am having is that output from Marked renders as text when it included proper HTML elements. Here is the problem Code:

```
class Main extends React.Component{
render() {
 console.log(this)
 console.log(marked('I am using __markdown__.'));
 return (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
        {marked('I am using __markdown__.')}
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <h1>Oh hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
 }
};

React.render( <Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and the html:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

thanks.

Comment: Why are you using markdown with React? You now have two html generating systems in your project (jsx and md). Are you loading the content from somewhere else and rendering? If you are using webpack consider using a tool like [markdown-loader](https://github.com/peerigon/markdown-loader) which uses the same lib as you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). React prevents you from xss, and this is the escape hatch.

```
<div
    className="col-md-6"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: marked('I am using __markdown__.')
    }}
/>
```

Comment: This can be very dangerous for the security of your app, especially if the source for the markdown comes from user input..

Comment: Marked has a `sanitize` option that should be used if the text to be converted comes from user input.